# Find `.gz` extension file and unpack with `tar`

Tags: linux

I want to find a gunzipped tarball file within my directory and unpack it. I have tried:

```
system("find . -name '*.gz' | tar -xvf -")
```

this produces the following error:

```
tar: Missing type keyword in mtree specification
x ./Library/rmarkdown_2.17.1.tar.gz
tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors.
```

`system` is a func in R to call linux commands.

Comment: You're piping file names into tar, but tar is expecting the content of a tar file. Not the same thing, doesn't work. Also, pretty certain that R also has a function to list directories which you should use rather than calling find.

Comment: Also, not all things ending in .gz are tar files that have been gripped. They might be in your case, but be wary, this is not even canonically the only thing that you suffix with .gz.

Comment: @MarcusMüller oh I see! I did not know that `tgz` would look for `tar.gz`, turns out my script above works when replacing `.gz` for `tgz` but it does not unpack anything. Is there a reference document for this? I tried `*.tar.gz` because I thought it would reference the suffix as is.

Comment: `tgz`  does **not** look for `tar.gz`. and in your question, you just tried `*.gz`, not `*.tar.gz`. So, you would have found `textfile.gz` just as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
find ./ -iname '*.tgz' -exec tar -xvf {} \;
```

This should work.

Comment: What does `-exec` and `{}` do in this case?

Comment: Execute a command. This usage is well-documented, save if you look for *find exec* on this site, you will literally find hundreds of good examples and explanations

Comment: I actually get errors with this; i.e. there is no escape. When I remove these I get an error with the semicolon, `find: -exec: no terminating ";" or "+"`

Comment: -exec tells find to run the command following it on the result of find.
{} is replaced by the name of the .tgz file.